# Внесение значений в двумерный массив

Tags: python, bs4

Работаю с html кодом и с помощью запроса извлекаю все Id, чтобы все извлечь, мне нужно использовать цикл

Имеется двумерный массив
*primary_array*
:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Мой код:

```
for i in counts:
        primary_array.append([0 for y in range(i)])

soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')    
reault = soup.select('tr.items_row')
for item in reault:
        for i in range(len(primary_array)):
            for j in range(len(primary_array[i])):
                title_block = item.select('tr.items_row td')
                primaryid = title_block[count].string.strip()
                primary_array[i][j] = primaryid
```

Проблема моего кода в том, что в массиве получаются одинаковые значения, я знаю почему так получается, но мне не приходит в голову, как можно по другому организовать вставку значений в массив, кто подскажет?

Comment: А что такое `count`? Эта переменная берётся ниоткуда и никак не меняется в вашем коде. Это нормально? Собственно, внутри циклов по `i` и `j` у вас вообще ничего кроме этих `i` и `j` не меняется. Лучше объясните - что вы вообще пытаетесь делать в этом коде?

Comment: Я не стал показывать весь код, потому что он большой. Значение **count** равно 3 и в данном случае оно на суть проблемы не влияет.
кроме **i** и **j** у меня так же меняется **item**.
**item** в свою очередь является объектом у которого мы достаем блок **title_block**  через 
 **select** , а уже потом , с этого блока вытягиваем **id**,   через **[  ]**

Comment: Нет, смотрите, внутри цикла по `item` у вас есть циклы по `i` и `j`, вот время этих циклов вы заполняете  всю матрицу `primary_array` **одним и тем же значением**, потому что там ничего вообще не меняется. Потом вы переходите к следующему значению `item` и **снова заполняете всю матрицу одним и тем же значением**. Вы должны объяснить - что вы хотите, чтобы было в матрице на самом деле?

Comment: То что они заполняются одними значения это я знаю. Мне нужно, чтобы я перебирал значения из **reault** и каждое последующее значение у меня заполнялось в массиве. Дело в том , что в **reault** несколько  id могут быть закреплены за 1 человеком, например первые 3 - относятся к одной персоне. И я хотел чтобы массивы в массиве служили контейнером для **id** каждого человека. То есть первый массив id относится к первому индивиду, второй массив ко второму. НО! самое главное, что я знаю количество **id**, которое закреплено за каждым - **j** отвечает за это. **i** определяет количество человек.

Comment: В данном случае у меня 4 человека, у всех по 2 **id** ,кроме 1го

Comment: Я пытался через break останавливать цикл, чтобы он не заполнял лишнее, одна при таком раскладе, **i** и **J** обнуляются